# Errors facing while importing android-support-v7-appcompat to eclipse

Tags: android

### What i have done:

1. I imported `android-support-v7-appcompat` as library project to
   eclipse
2. I am getting the errors below how can i resolve this

### ERROR:

```
E:\Workspaces\Workspace-7\android-support-v7-appcompat\res\values-v17\styles_rtl.xml:70: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:textAlignment'.
[2015-01-06 21:27:26 - android-support-v7-appcompat] 
[2015-01-06 21:27:26 - android-support-v7-appcompat] E:\Workspaces\Workspace-7\android-support-v7-appcompat\res\values-v21\themes_base.xml:26: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Theme.Material'.
[2015-01-06 21:27:26 - android-support-v7-appcompat] 
[2015-01-06 21:27:26 - android-support-v7-appcompat] E:\Workspaces\Workspace-7\android-support-v7-appcompat\res\values-v21\themes_base.xml:31: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Theme.Material.Light'.
[2015-01-06 21:27:26 - android-support-v7-appcompat] 
[2015-01-06 21:27:26 - android-support-v7-appcompat] E:\Workspaces\Workspace-7\android-support-v7-appcompat\res\values-v21\themes_base.xml:36: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Theme.Material.Dialog'.
[2015-01-06 21:27:26 - android-support-v7-appcompat] 
[2015-01-06 21:27:26 - android-support-v7-appcompat] E:\Workspaces\Workspace-7\android-support-v7-appcompat\res\values-v21\themes_base.xml:41: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Theme.Material.Light.Dialog'.
[2015-01-06 21:27:26 - android-support-v7-appcompat] 
[2015-01-06 21:27:26 - android-support-v7-appcompat] E:\Workspaces\Workspace-7\android-support-v7-appcompat\res\values-v11\themes_base.xml:338: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:actionModeShareDrawable'.
[2015-01-06 21:27:26 - android-support-v7-appcompat] 
[2015-01-06 21:27:26 - android-support-v7-appcompat] E:\Workspaces\Workspace-7\android-support-v7-appcompat\res\values-v14\themes_base.xml:29: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:actionModeShareDrawable'.
[2015-01-06 21:27:26 - android-support-v7-appcompat] 
[2015-01-06 21:27:26 - android-support-v7-appcompat] E:\Workspaces\Workspace-7\android-support-v7-appcompat\res\values-v11\themes_base.xml:345: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:actionModeShareDrawable'.
[2015-01-06 21:27:26 - android-support-v7-appcompat] 
[2015-01-06 21:27:26 - android-support-v7-appcompat] E:\Workspaces\Workspace-7\android-support-v7-appcompat\res\values-v14\themes_base.xml:37: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:actionModeShareDrawable'.
[2015-01-06 21:27:26 - android-support-v7-appcompat] 
[2015-01-06 21:27:26 - android-support-v7-appcompat] E:\Workspaces\Workspace-7\android-support-v7-appcompat\res\values-v11\themes_base.xml:352: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:actionModeShareDrawable'.
[2015-01-06 21:27:26 - android-support-v7-appcompat] 
[2015-01-06 21:27:26 - android-support-v7-appcompat] E:\Workspaces\Workspace-7\android-support-v7-appcompat\res\values-v14\themes_base.xml:45: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:actionModeShareDrawable'.
[2015-01-06 21:27:26 - android-support-v7-appcompat] 
[2015-01-06 21:27:26 - android-support-v7-appcompat] E:\Workspaces\Workspace-7\android-support-v7-appcompat\res\values-v11\themes_base.xml:359: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:actionModeShareDrawable'.
[2015-01-06 21:27:26 - android-support-v7-appcompat] 
[2015-01-06 21:27:26 - android-support-v7-appcompat] E:\Workspaces\Workspace-7\android-support-v7-appcompat\res\values-v14\themes_base.xml:53: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:actionModeShareDrawable'.
[2015-01-06 21:27:26 - android-support-v7-appcompat] 
[2015-01-06 21:27:26 - android-support-v7-appcompat] E:\Workspaces\Workspace-7\android-support-v7-appcompat\res\values-v21\themes_base.xml:202: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:ThemeOverlay.Material'.
[2015-01-06 21:27:26 - android-support-v7-appcompat] 
[2015-01-06 21:27:26 - android-support-v7-appcompat] E:\Workspaces\Workspace-7\android-support-v7-appcompat\res\values-v21\themes_base.xml:212: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:ThemeOverlay.Material.Light'.
[2015-01-06 21:27:26 - android-support-v7-appcompat] 
[2015-01-06 21:27:26 - android-support-v7-appcompat] E:\Workspaces\Workspace-7\android-support-v7-appcompat\res\values-v21\themes_base.xml:205: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:ThemeOverlay.Material.Dark'.
[2015-01-06 21:27:26 - android-support-v7-appcompat] 
[2015-01-06 21:27:26 - android-support-v7-appcompat] E:\Workspaces\Workspace-7\android-support-v7-appcompat\res\values-v21\themes_base.xml:219: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:ThemeOverlay.Material.ActionBar'.
[2015-01-06 21:27:26 - android-support-v7-appcompat] 
[2015-01-06 21:27:26 - android-support-v7-appcompat] E:\Workspaces\Workspace-7\android-support-v7-appcompat\res\values-v21\themes_base.xml:223: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:ThemeOverlay.Material.Dark.ActionBar'.
[2015-01-06 21:27:26 - android-support-v7-appcompat] 
[2015-01-06 21:27:26 - android-support-v7-appcompat] E:\Workspaces\Workspace-7\android-support-v7-appcompat\res\values-v21\themes_base.xml:81: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:colorAccent'.
[2015-01-06 21:27:26 - android-support-v7-appcompat] 
[2015-01-06 21:27:26 - android-support-v7-appcompat] E:\Workspaces\Workspace-7\android-support-v7-appcompat\res\values-v21\themes_base.xml:83: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:colorControlActivated'.
[2015-01-06 21:27:26 - android-support-v7-appcompat] 
[2015-01-06 21:27:26 - android-support-v7-appcompat] E:\Workspaces\Workspace-7\android-support-v7-appcompat\res\values-v21\themes_base.xml:84: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:colorControlHighlight'.
[2015-01-06 21:27:26 - android-support-v7-appcompat] 
[2015-01-06 21:27:26 - android-support-v7-appcompat] E:\Workspaces\Workspace-7\android-support-v7-appcompat\res\values-v21\themes_base.xml:82: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:colorControlNormal'.
[2015-01-06 21:27:26 - android-support-v7-appcompat] 
[2015-01-06 21:27:26 - android-support-v7-appcompat] E:\Workspaces\Workspace-7\android-support-v7-appcompat\res\values-v21\themes_base.xml:79: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:colorPrimary'.
[2015-01-06 21:27:26 - android-support-v7-appcompat] 
[2015-01-06 21:27:26 - android-support-v7-appcompat] E:\Workspaces\Workspace-7\android-support-v7-appcompat\res\values-v21\themes_base.xml:80: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:colorPrimaryDark'.
[2015-01-06 21:27:26 - android-support-v7-appcompat] 
[2015-01-06 21:27:26 - android-support-v7-appcompat] E:\Workspaces\Workspace-7\android-support-v7-appcompat\res\values-v21\themes_base.xml:118: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:colorAccent'.
[2015-01-06 21:27:26 - android-support-v7-appcompat] 
[2015-01-06 21:27:26 - android-support-v7-appcompat] E:\Workspaces\Workspace-7\android-support-v7-appcompat\res\values-v21\themes_base.xml:120: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:colorControlActivated'.
[2015-01-06 21:27:26 - android-support-v7-appcompat] 
[2015-01-06 21:27:26 - android-support-v7-appcompat] E:\Workspaces\Workspace-7\android-support-v7-appcompat\res\values-v21\themes_base.xml:121: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:colorControlHighlight'.
[2015-01-06 21:27:26 - android-support-v7-appcompat] 
[2015-01-06 21:27:26 - android-support-v7-appcompat] E:\Workspaces\Workspace-7\android-support-v7-appcompat\res\values-v21\themes_base.xml:119: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:colorControlNormal'.
[2015-01-06 21:27:26 - android-support-v7-appcompat] 
[2015-01-06 21:27:26 - android-support-v7-appcompat] E:\Workspaces\Workspace-7\android-support-v7-appcompat\res\values-v21\themes_base.xml:116: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:colorPrimary'.
[2015-01-06 21:27:26 - android-support-v7-appcompat] 
[2015-01-06 21:27:26 - android-support-v7-appcompat] E:\Workspaces\Workspace-7\android-support-v7-appcompat\res\values-v21\themes_base.xml:117: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:colorPrimaryDark'.
[2015-01-06 21:27:26 - android-support-v7-appcompat] 
[2015-01-06 21:27:26 - android-support-v7-appcompat] E:\Workspaces\Workspace-7\android-support-v7-appcompat\res\values-v21\themes_base.xml:155: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:colorAccent'.
[2015-01-06 21:27:26 - android-support-v7-appcompat] 
[2015-01-06 21:27:26 - android-support-v7-appcompat] E:\Workspaces\Workspace-7\android-support-v7-appcompat\res\values-v21\themes_base.xml:157: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:colorControlActivated'.
[2015-01-06 21:27:26 - android-support-v7-appcompat] 
[2015-01-06 21:27:26 - android-support-v7-appcompat] E:\Workspaces\Workspace-7\android-support-v7-appcompat\res\values-v21\themes_base.xml:158: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:colorControlHighlight'.
[2015-01-06 21:27:26 - android-support-v7-appcompat] 
[2015-01-06 21:27:26 - android-support-v7-appcompat] E:\Workspaces\Workspace-7\android-support-v7-appcompat\res\values-v21\themes_base.xml:156: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:colorControlNormal'.
[2015-01-06 21:27:26 - android-support-v7-appcompat] 
[2015-01-06 21:27:26 - android-support-v7-appcompat] E:\Workspaces\Workspace-7\android-support-v7-appcompat\res\values-v21\themes_base.xml:153: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:colorPrimary'.
[2015-01-06 21:27:26 - android-support-v7-appcompat] 
[2015-01-06 21:27:26 - android-support-v7-appcompat] E:\Workspaces\Workspace-7\android-support-v7-appcompat\res\values-v21\themes_base.xml:154: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:colorPrimaryDark'.
[2015-01-06 21:27:26 - android-support-v7-appcompat] 
[2015-01-06 21:27:26 - android-support-v7-appcompat] E:\Workspaces\Workspace-7\android-support-v7-appcompat\res\values-v21\themes_base.xml:192: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:colorAccent'.
[2015-01-06 21:27:26 - android-support-v7-appcompat] 
[2015-01-06 21:27:26 - android-support-v7-appcompat] E:\Workspaces\Workspace-7\android-support-v7-appcompat\res\values-v21\themes_base.xml:194: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:colorControlActivated'.
[2015-01-06 21:27:26 - android-support-v7-appcompat] 
[2015-01-06 21:27:26 - android-support-v7-appcompat] E:\Workspaces\Workspace-7\android-support-v7-appcompat\res\values-v21\themes_base.xml:195: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:colorControlHighlight'.
[2015-01-06 21:27:26 - android-support-v7-appcompat] 
[2015-01-06 21:27:26 - android-support-v7-appcompat] E:\Workspaces\Workspace-7\android-support-v7-appcompat\res\values-v21\themes_base.xml:193: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:colorControlNormal'.
[2015-01-06 21:27:26 - android-support-v7-appcompat] 
[2015-01-06 21:27:26 - android-support-v7-appcompat] E:\Workspaces\Workspace-7\android-support-v7-appcompat\res\values-v21\themes_base.xml:190: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:colorPrimary'.
[2015-01-06 21:27:26 - android-support-v7-appcompat] 
[2015-01-06 21:27:26 - android-support-v7-appcompat] E:\Workspaces\Workspace-7\android-support-v7-appcompat\res\values-v21\themes_base.xml:191: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:colorPrimaryDark'.
```

### UPDATE

I deleted V4 library in this 
now i get beloow error but above error is resolved

```
error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.ActionButton'.
```

Answer (score 1):

### RESOLVED IT MYSELF

1. Right Click on appcompat_v7 library and select Properties
2. Now, Click on Android Option,
3. Set Project Build Path as Android 5.0 (API level 21)
4. Apply Changes.
5. Now Clean + Build appcompat_v7 library and your projects